# Application.ontime not canceling

Tags: excel, vba

I'm building a form that can take the values from the clipboard and auto fill itself.
In order to get the values I use application.ontime to run a macro every two seconds and read the clipboard. The start is done in userform initialize.
That works fine.

```
Sub Userform_Initialize()
    On Error Resume Next
    fireTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=fireTime, Procedure:="copy", Schedule:=True
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

If I close the userform I added a queryclose to make sure the copy macro stops:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=fireTime, Procedure:="copy", Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

Works fine also.

The actual macro is this:

```
Public fireTime As Date


Sub copy()
   
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    Dim oData   As New DataObject 
    Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
    Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard
    
    strPaste = DataObj.GetText(1)
    Row1 = Split(strPaste, vbNewLine)(0)
    col = Split(Row1, vbTab) 
    
    If UBound(Split(col(14), "-")) = 2 Then
        If Len(col(0)) = 7 Then
            If Left(col(3), 4) = "4600" Then
                oData.SetText Text:=Empty 'Clear
                oData.PutInClipboard 'take in the clipboard to empty it

                UF_RegistreraVM.TB_LevNr.Text = col(0)
                Levnr = col(0)
                ' ... and so on..
                
                'Line below does not work
                Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=fireTime, Procedure:="copy", Schedule:=False
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    
ErrHandler:
    On Error Resume Next
    fireTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=fireTime, Procedure:="copy", Schedule:=True
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

And the only line that does not work is when I set application.ontime to false in the nested ifs.
That line is the same as the one in queryclose, but it doesn't work here.
When I debug the code errors on that line and due to `On Error GoTo ErrHandler` it jums down to ErrHandler and sets a new time to run the macro.

What is the issue that with the code, why can't I turn of the ontime inside the ifs?

Comment: You are already executing the copy macro, doesn't it means that the OnTime was already canceled? I don't think you can cancel a OnTime event that was already triggered...

Comment: Yes.. You are right, so obvious. I need to just exit the sub and not worry about the ontime.

Comment: @FaneDuru As Vincent says. The FireTime is set to a time in the past at that moment so there is nothing to schedule to false. When it tries to set something to false that does not exist it errors and jumps to ErrHandler.